# Периодический и апериодический процессы

Tags: c, процесс

Возник вопрос о вот таких вот процессах.
Теорию про них вроде бы понял, но не понятна одна вещь, а именно количество экземпляров у каждого процесса.

Переодический процесс (который с какой-то периодичностью стартует) имеет один экземпляр или *на каждый период исполнения создается новый экземпляр*?

Т.е. пусть у нас есть программа:

```
printf("Hello world! %ld", getpid());
```

То с заданной периодичностью мы будем видеть:

> Hello world! 123
>
> Hello world! 125
>
> Hello world! 127

Такой же вопрос про апериодические процессы. Как я понял создается только один экземпляр, и он будет "жить", пока не закончит свое исполнение?

Т.е. тот же кусок кода нам выдаст следующее:

> Hello world! 253

Правильно ли мое суждение, что периодический процесс это много экземпляров, а апериодический это один экземпляр?

Интересуют ОСРВ!

Comment: Ну, очевидно, каждый раз, когда процесс _стартует_, это новый процесс.

Comment: А что вы понимаете вообще под _периодическим_ и _непериодическим_ процессами?

Comment: @VladD Это что-то из радиотехники...

Comment: @VladD, периодический процесс это процесс, который имеет переиод запуска и deadline, также мы может рассчитать когда он будет стартовать (период же мы знаем), мне в голову приходят два варианта:
1) запускается один процесс, потом при подходе к deadline процесс вытесняется или просто засыпает, затем при подходе периода, процесс возобновляется или просыпается.
2) на каждый период запускается свой отдельный экзмепляр процесса, т.е. должно быть гарантировано, что к deadline процесс выполнит все необходимые операции.
Апериодический процесс может стартовать в любое время.

Comment: @Roman, точно не из радиотехники :)
Такие процессы рассматриваются при планировании в системах реального времени.

Comment: @rinatd: Ну так и то и другое можно реализовать как с одним процессом, который будет ждать нужного времени (хоть периодического, хоть нет, только бы была возможность выяснить, когда ему нужно выполнит действия), как с запуском процесса в нужный момент отдельной утилитой. Непонятно, в чём трудность.

Comment: @VladD, трудность не в реализации, а в правильности трактовки теории. По моему правильно одно из двух суждений: или процесс каждый период перезапуксается, или он спит до следующего периода.

Comment: Вам правильно сказали в ответе, что в распространенных сейчас ОС такого понятия нет. Что же касается теории, (IMHO) интересным может быть случай, когда в рамках одного и того же переодического процесса (с тем же PID в терминах \*nix-ов) с заданым интервалом запускается (с самого начала) одна и та же программа (хотя, м.б. и разные программы, но с тем же PID). / Представляете как это принципиально можно реализовать?

Comment: @avp, к сожалению ответ не подходит. Случай, предложенный вами интересен, как мне кажется, в userspace эту проблему не решить.

Comment: Ну, отчего же? Простейшее решение -- после выполнения запланированной работы ожидание в `pause()`, а далее `execve()` в обработчике `alarm()`, которым и планируете перезапуск.

Comment: @avp, верно. А если будут нормальные процессы без искусственных pause()?

Comment: Если дойдет до конца и не будет ждать (в pause (или getchar или придумайте сами где можно ждать и ждать ... (например, sleep в цикле))), то просто завершится до запланированного таймаута. Ну, сами подумайте, как процесс работает... Можно, конечно, просто сразу после выполнения работы себя перезапустить, можно поспать немного и перезапустить ...

Comment: И потом, что значит "искусственной" и что такое "нормальные процессы"? Не очень понимаю. Все они просто процессы и просто системные вызовы.

Comment: @avp, я образно выразился. pause() и другие функции работают непосредственно в коде самого приложения, а если сделать так, чтобы приложение об этом не знало, извне так сказать. Под искусственными я имел ввиду так называемый workaround. А нормальный процесс - это процесс без применения описанных приёмов.
Я понимаю, что процесс завершится, но в таком случае pid не сохранится.

Comment: Судя по книге "Hard Real-Time computing systems", все-таки пер. процессы, это каждый раз новый инстанс. Если убежусь в этом выделю в ответ.

Comment: Возможно. В каждой области все-таки своя терминология.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В современных операционных системах нет понятий *периодический* и *апериодический* процессы. Вы можете считать, однако, процесс периодическим, если он запускается с каким-то определённым периодом, например, с помощью таких подсистем как `cron` или `anacron` (для периодически выключающихся систем, таких как десктопы).

Во всех случаях, когда процесс заново запускается (а именно так происходит, когда процесс выполняется периодически `cron`-ом), он получает новый PID.

**Обновление 1.**

Что касается систем реального времени, то этот вопрос здесь приобретает
совсем другое звучание. В теории операционных систем реального времени (RTOS) выделяют периодические и апериодические задачи (periodic and aperiodic tasks). *Периодическая задача* это та, которая выполняется в соответствии с заранее чётко известным расписанием и накладывает жёсткие ограничения на время исполнения (hard deadlines). В отличие от этого *апериодические задачи* исполняются в заранее неопределённое время и могут накладывать как жёсткие, так и мягкие требования к времени исполнения (soft deadlines и hard deadlines).

Как именно будет жить процесс, будет ли он запускаться заново или просто получать управление в определённое время, может *зависеть от реализации* и не определяется в теории как таковой, но *во всех известных мне в настоящее время реализациях* процесс не завершается, выполнение происходит в рамках одного процесса, он просто *откладывается на время*, когда будет необходим его следующий запуск.

Например, вот как реализуется периодическая задача в FreeRTOS:

```
 // Perform an action every 10 ticks.
 void vTaskFunction( void * pvParameters )
 {
 TickType_t xLastWakeTime;
 const TickType_t xFrequency = 10;

     // Initialise the xLastWakeTime variable with the current time.
     xLastWakeTime = xTaskGetTickCount();

     for( ;; )
     {
         // Wait for the next cycle.
         vTaskDelayUntil( &xLastWakeTime, xFrequency );

         // Perform action here.
     }
 }
```

Источник: *FreeRTOS Scheduler API Documentation*, [vTaskDelayUntil](http://www.freertos.org/vtaskdelayuntil.html)

Как видно из примера, выполнение происходит в рамках одного процесса.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но распространенные ОС меня не интересуют, дополнил вопрос, что рассматриваются ОСРВ

Comment: @rinatd: Смотрите обновление

Comment: спасибо за ответ, не ожидал, что это зависит от реализации ОС.